# Cast em ponteiro void

Tags: c, ponteiro, conversão-de-tipo, cast, void

O código abaixo estava funcionando como esperado, porem mudei o tipo da info na estrutura Lista de `Retangulo*` para `void*` e tentei de todo jeito dar cast mas continuo com o seguinte erro:

> ```
> t.c: In function ‘imprimir’:  
> t.c:40:38: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer   
>    printf("Base.....: %.2f\n", l->info->b);  
>                                       ^
> t.c:40:38: error: request for member ‘b’ in something not a structure or union  
> t.c:41:38: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer  
>    printf("Altura...: %.2f\n", l->info->h);  
>                                       ^
> t.c:41:38: error: request for member ‘h’ in something not a structure or union  
> t.c:42:41: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer  
>    printf("Área.....: %.2f\n\n", l->info->b * l->info->h);  
> t.c:42:41: error: request for member ‘b’ in something not a structure or union
> t.c:42:54: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer   
>    printf("Área.....: %.2f\n\n", l->info->b * l->info->h);
>                                                       ^
> t.c:42:54: error: request for member ‘h’ in something not a structure or union
> ```

Código:

```
typedef struct retangulo
{
    float b;
    float h;
} Retangulo;

typedef struct lista
{
    void *info;
    struct lista *prox;
} Lista;

Lista* inserir(Lista* l, float base, float alt)
{

    Lista* novo=malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    Retangulo* ret=malloc(sizeof(Retangulo));

    ret->b=base;
    ret->h=alt;

    novo->info=ret;
    novo->prox=l;

    return novo;
}

void imprimir(Lista* l)
{

    for (; l!=NULL; l=l->prox)
    {
        printf("Base.....: %.2f\n", l->info->b);
        printf("Altura...: %.2f\n", l->info->h);
        printf("Área.....: %.2f\n\n", l->info->b * l->info->h);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void*` não pode ser desreferenciado(*dereferenced*) uma vez que é um ponteiro genérico. Qual a intenção de estar a usar `void*` em vez de `Retangulo*`, considerando que não poderá usar o ponteiro sem o converter para um tipo especifico primeiro ?

Answer (score 1):

O erro é porque o compilador não sabe como tratar o ponteiro `info`, uma vez que ele não aponta para um tipo específico de dados. Então a solução seria fazer o cast, por exemplo:

```
printf("Base.....: %.2f\n", ((Retangulo*) l->info)->b);
```

Mas não parece haver necessidade de declarar a variável `info` como `void *`.